# strings based on dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

i have these problem in dynamic programming, i need to provide a solution based on dybamic programming:

We have strings with length n, and contain only {A,B,C} charachters.string is "winner" only if it does not contain 3 A's in a row and contain at most one 'B'. 
example:
There are 43 "winners" strings with length 4.
i need to suggest an algorithm that calculates the number of "winning" strings with length n. it need to run in O(n) complexity.

What i thought about so far is:
3 paramaters: n- length of the current string, bCount=1, aCount=2.
in every iteration the n decreasing by 1. if we used b so bCount decreasing by 1. if we used A so aCount decreasing by 1 but it initialized to 2 if any other charachter had inserted.

i need to make it formal and clear, hope you can help me fill the gaps and make the solution formal.

I really tried hard to solve it, i would be very thankful if anyone can help me.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First lets look at B. You either have no B and therefor a string of length n with only A and C or you have a string with 1 B and 2 sub strings with cumulated length of n - 1 with only A and C. So if you can calculate all valid A and C combinations for strings of any length the rest becomes easy.

```
function winners(n) {
    let sum = combos[n]
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += combos[i] * combos[n - i - 1]
    return sum
}
```

How to calculate the A, C combos? You can use dynamic programming (always look how many strings end in A, C and AA):

```
combos = [1, 2]
endsInA = 1
endsInC = 1
endsInAA = 0
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    combos[i] = (endsInA + endsInC) * 2 + endsInAA
    let c = endsInC
    endsInC = endsInA + endsInAA + c
    endsInAA = endsInA
    endsInA = c
}
```

It is `(endsInA + endsInC) * 2 + endsInAA` because after those ending in A or C you can put either an A or a C while after those ending in AA you can only put a C. The update rule is also quite easy to understand. You have as many strings ending in AA as you had strings ending in A before and as many Strings ending in A as you had strings ending in C before. C can be put behind all the strings, so it is just the sum of all the possible endings from before. You could also update first and then just take the sum of all the endings to get the number of combos.

[Everything put together and optimized for a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mnge4aq7/1/)

It takes O(n) to calculate the combinations and O(n) to calculate the winners and therefore the whole complexity is O(n).